# Load Jquery after async ajax update in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a ASP.net page that is jquery heavy.

on this page I have a gridview inside a updatepanel so I can make a asynch update.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMail" runat="server" GridLines="None" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="mail_RowDataBound"
CssClass="gridview" DataKeyNames="id">


<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<RowStyle ForeColor="#0072BC" HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="draggable" />

</asp:GridView>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<!-- Hidden Link button for Async call back -->
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnLoadData" onclick="btnLoadData_Click" runat="server" 
 Text="Fill GridView" CssClass="none"></asp:LinkButton> <!-- hidden-->

<a href="javascript: AsyncUpdateGridView()">A sync update</a>
<!-- testing purposes only-->

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

so with this little hack i click hte linkbutton to update the gridview which works fine. Eventually the AsyncUpdateGridView() which just calles the _dopostback method of the hidden linkbutton will be in Javascript.

The problem I have, is my GridView has columns which are Jquery DatePickers and Jquery fancy Drop Down Box's. They are loaded with this javascript call:

```
  function OnLoadPage() {
            $(".jqueryselector").selectbox({
                effect: "fade"
            });

            $(".jquerydatepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            OnLoadPage();
        }
```

The reason I made the OnLoadPage() function was because I tried calling that after I did the _DoPostBack call after the update.

However this doesnt work. So now when the page fist loads, all the jquery datepicker, drop down boxs and other fancy things I have work in the GridView. But after the asynch Callback it reloads with all the default html.

Comment: Have you tried calling the [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) in your code behind when a post back occurs to reissue your **OnLoadPage** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready` is not executed after ajax panel call has finished and html block is updated. You need to register to events provided by asp.net ajax for this. You can use `begin_request` and `end_request` for executing some javascript before and afterr ajax call, If you want to call the javascript function after the completion of ajax call you need to use end_request and for before ajax call you need begin_request, More about them over [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx)

```
   function OnLoadPage() {
        $(".jqueryselector").selectbox({
            effect: "fade"
        });

        $(".jquerydatepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
    }


Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);


Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);


function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args)
{

}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
     OnLoadPage();
}
```

Comment: OnLoadPage() is a javascript function.. so i cant call it in EndRequestHndler..?

Comment: Yes you can call it 100%. I have updated my answer and given msdn link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx